# How does the warmup service work in python google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Can someone give an example of how the warmup inbound service works in the python runtime of Google App Engine?

I've read this: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Inbound_Services, but it doesn't give me much of an example after the GET request is sent (I can't seem to ever pick it up)

My app.yaml looks like this:

```
application: whatevs
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

builtins:
- datastore_admin: on

inbound_services:
- warmup

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /_ah/warmup
  script: main.py
  login: admin 

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

my main.py looks like this:

```
def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                     [("/", views.LandingPage),
                      ("/_ah/warmup", views.WarmupHandler)
                      ],
                     debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)
```

WarmupHandler looks like this:

```
class WarmupHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    """
    Called on app init
    """
    def get(self):
        current_user = users.get_current_user()
        return
```

However, WarmupHandler never seems to get called (I have breakpoints and lots of debug code). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What debug code? You don't show any here. And how are you debugging it? Are you sure your breakpoints get hit at all?

Comment: Good point, Nick. Turns out I misunderstood the expected functionality of a 'warmup', as Teemu points out below. So, it's not guaranteed to get triggered. That explains why my handler never got hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine sends warm up requests only if there is some constant traffic on your app. It won't get always called if instances stand mostly idle.

Comment: Thanks Teemu. Is there something similar to warmup that executes every time an app is "started"? I guess I can just call my own admin handler the first time, by hand.

Comment: you could write main.py like this:

    application = webapp.WSGIApplication( ... )
    <add initialization suff here>
    def main():
        run_wsgi_app(application)

Everything outside main is executed only once.

Comment: Good point. I was looking for something that executes only the 'first time' the app is deployed/launched. I guess it is easier to just have an admin-only handler that is launched manually. Your point about the warmup functionality answers my (and others) question though, so thank you.

Comment: This isn't quite accurate. Warmup requests get sent any time App Engine is starting up a new instance of your app in response to demand, but doesn't have a request to send it. For instance, if you set "min idle instances" to at least 1, you'll generally get a warmup request any time a new instance is needed.