# How do I perform one-time initializations in Python in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am a **GAE/Python** newbie. I have a number of system and application variables that I would like to set once and have them apply to all `.py` files in my application. Can anyone tell me how I accomplish that *(have a place that is run once only at application startup)*?  Sort of like what one would do with a config file in other applications.

I am running Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

On GAE, modules are loaded just once in the runtime ([they are cached](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#App_Caching)), so you can create one module with all initializations, globals etc. If you use threadsafe=true in you app.yaml, make sure you handle these globals correctly (in thread safe way).

Note, that on new instance the initialization is performed again. If your init is very long process (seconds), the good way to go is to precompute it, store in the datastore and load it in the init module from datastore again.

Comment: Is this as simple as creating a new folder (e.g. name = "init") and adding an __init__.py file and declaring the variables to be global in that file?  Are these globals then global everywhere in all modules in that application? (excuse my ignorance if I am way off.)  Thanks.

Comment: You do not need to create new folder. You can create just your init.py script and declare all variables and globals there and then import it into you application modules. These globals are global within one instace - so if you change the value of the global variable, it is not changed across the whole application (across many instances on which the application is running), but only on the one instance, where you changed the variable. If you want to use and globals across the whole application, you have to use datastore/memcache, which is globally consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to use lib_config to define and override your own constants and hooks.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig

Answer (score 0):

One of the recommended ways with 2.7 on appengine is to set environment variables in app.yaml.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#env_variables

(as other answers posted here, it's not the only way.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I am just trying to set some folder paths and prepopulate a number of lists with allowable values and I do not want to have to populate these multiple times.  E.g. I want to initialize the list of allowable statuses as follows: StatusList = ['Pending Translation', 'Pending Review', 'Published', 'etc']; Would this be considered an environment variable?  What would the code look like in app.yaml?  Thanks.

Comment: You forgot that bit of detail in you original question ;-) Lists do work in yaml files, however using env_variables in app.yaml does not work.  So this is not appropriate for your requirements.  I use a seperate settings.yaml for all the more detail additional config I need.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, setting.yaml might be what I need. Basically I want to execute specific functions when certain events happen such as start application, initialize sessions, user login, when  value of certain variables, happen, etc.  Where can I find more information about settings.yaml and the various event triggers provided by GAE?  Thanks.

Comment: you can create any yaml file you want and deploy it with your code. You will then need to open and parse the yaml file in your own code when you want it's content.s

Answer (score -1):

if i understood your query well, i think, you could use [warmup request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235716/how-does-the-warmup-service-work-in-python-google-app-engine) at GAE.

In this you could actually init your all var's and methods which you requires regularly..

Comment: You need to be aware that warmup requests aren't always sent to new instances. When a new instance is started by a user request, that user request is sent directly to the new instance, bypassing the warmup request. So if there is initialization code that must absolutely run for each instance, warmup requests aren't the appropriate place to put this code.